# NX - @nrwl/workspace:run-commands does not save artifacts to /dist in case of a cache hit

Tags: build, serverless, nrwl-nx

I have to package one of my apps for serverless.

This is the command I use in project.json

```
"build": {
  "executor": "@nrwl/workspace:run-commands",
  "options": {
    "outputPath": "../../dist/apps/my-app",
    "cwd": "apps/my-app",
    "color": true,
    "command": "serverless package --package ../../dist/apps/my-app"
  }
}
```

If I remove the `/dist` folder, and then run the command once, everything works (the `/dist` folder gets populated with the files for serverless deploy).

Now I do the same once again: I delete the `/dist` folder, and run the command again. This time NX hits the cache, the command executes in one second, but the `/dist` folder doesn't get re-created.

Does anybody if it's possible to configure the NX command correctly?

Ideally I would like to make it work like `@nrwl/node:build`:

```
"build": {
  "executor": "@nrwl/node:build",
  "options": {
    "outputPath": "dist/apps/my-app",
    "main": "apps/my-app/src/index.ts",
    "tsConfig": "apps/my-app/tsconfig.app.json"
  }
}
```

This command works exactly as I would expect: and the `/dist` folder is re-generated even in case of a cache hit.